# View Not Returning HttpResponse Object

Tags: python, django, forms

So I have a view called index that may or may not receive a POST form. I've seen questions like this asked on here and notice that most of the time it seems to be a simple logic error within the view, but the way I have my view written, the render call is outside of all conditionals, extracted so that it should always be called. The view is such:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

import datetime

myUsers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'Guest']

def index(request):
    # grab user if we've submitted login form from this page
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'myUser' in request.POST:
            request.session['myUser'] = request.POST['myUser']
    # make login default guest if not logged in
    elif not 'myUser' in request.session:
        request.session['myUser'] = 'Guest'

    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'myUsers': myUsers})
```

I'm fairly stuck as to the solution, and help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's the traceback as well.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://transcode50.com/home/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'bootstrap_toolkit',
 'transcode',
 'transcode50',
 'home',
 'books')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  133.                     raise ValueError("The view %s.%s didn't return an HttpResponse object." % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /home/
Exception Value: The view home.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object.
```

Comment: Can you show the traceback of the error as well?

Comment: Based on that code I don't see how this could happen either.  Any chance it's an indentation problem?  That might not show up nicely in code copied here.

Comment: That was indeed the case; submitted my own answer to reflect. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by an indentation problem, therefore: too localized.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, per Peter, was that the indentation was off. It was perfectly lined up in my text editor, but shift-tabbing all lines and retabbing them fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should tweak something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
     for user in myUsers:
        if user in request.POST:
            request.session['myUser'] = request.POST['myUser']
```

request.POST is dictionary-like object, and your myUsers is a list. I dont think you can do myUser in request.POST directly in python. Its my 2 cent.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#id3 - "QueryDict implements all the standard dictionary methods, because it’s a subclass of dictionary."  The example view is testing for the presence of the `myUser` key in the POST querydict in a valid way.